# C# - WPF modal window

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

Is it possible to switch or activate other windows when modal window is open?

```
Window1 window = new Window1();
window.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you can do something like the following:

```
Window1 window = new Window1();    
window.Activate();
```

This will activate window and bring it to the foreground.

Comment: Actually I have 3 windows like Window1, Window2 and Window3. When I start the Project Window1 and Window3 opens at the same time (always open) and Window2 opens when I click a button. Window2 is a modal window but I have to access Window 3 while Window2 is open.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question once again. Do you need to access the Window3 when Window2 is open?

Comment: Yes, exactly !.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to set the control back to parent form from a modal window(That's the point of using Modal Window). You can use non modal window.

```
window.Show();
```

If you use `window.Activate();` it will not show the form.

Comment: Agree with this point, you could use usual window instead of modal.

Comment: Okay then, I just wanted to know if it is possible. Thanks for answers / comments :)